# gdb printing array/strings with a certain offset

Tags: c, assembly, gdb

I have the following defined:

```
strings:    .asciz  "Once\n", "upon\n", "a\n", "time\n", "...\n", ""
```

And I can see the label is stored at the following memory address, `600109`:

```
>>> info va strings
Non-debugging symbols:
0x0000000000600109  strings
```

I can print this as:

```
>>> x/s 0x0000000000600109
0x600109:   "Once\n"
>>> x/s 0x0000000000600109+6
0x60010f:   "upon\n"
# etc...
```

Or referencing the variable to get the first string:

```
>>> x/s &strings
0x600109:   "Once\n"
```

How do I do proper offsets in `gdb` to do addition on the memory address -- for example, to be able to do `x/s &strings+6` to get the value `"upon\n"`?

What would be the correct way to do the following?

```
>>> x/s &strings+6
# Cannot perform pointer math on incomplete type "<data variable, no debug info>", try casting to a known type, or void *.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast this to `(void *)` to be able to do addition/subtraction on the memory address:

```
>>> x/s     6 + (void *) &strings
0x60010f:   "upon\n"
```

Comment: Arithmetic on `void*` is undefined. While it happens to work here, there is no reason to do so here: just use `char*` instead.

Comment: @EmployedRussian I see. Want to post an answer and I'll accept it then. Also, as far as types go is `gdb` more or less `c`? Or are there any differences? I usually just do (void *) for everything related to print, but from what you show above that seems incorrect

Comment: There is no need for separate answer: you can just edit this one. GDB tries to evaluate expressions using the language of current file. Arithmetic on `void*` is a GCC extension. I am just saying that there is no need for non-standard operations here.